# How to read CSV files in lua

Tags: csv, lua

I am trying to read a .csv file that has length and quantity columns. I am able to read the first column ( 12.5, 10, 8....) but the quantity field is always empty. I am obviously new to lua and was wondering if anyone had an idea as to why by quantity is always empty.

```
function ReadFileNameWindows(PassedInWindowsPath)
local fileList = {}
for line in io.lines(PassedInWindowsPath) do
local length,quantity = line:match("%s*(.-),%s*(.-)")
    print(length)
    print(quantity)
    fileList[#fileList + 1] = { length = length, quantity = quantity } 
    end
```

Comment: Without at least a sample of the csv file it is mostly guesswork, but I'm thinking you need `line:match("%s*(.+),%s*(.+)")` there. https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html `Like '*', the modifier '-' also matches zero or more occurrences of characters of the original class. However, instead of matching the longest sequence, it matches the shortest one.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern is wrong. `line:match("%s*(.-),%s*(.-)")` will first consume some spacing, then match some characters until the first `,`, then again match some spacing, then match *nothing* (the empty string). That's because `.-` is a lazy match: It matches as little as possible (can be zero characters) for the pattern to match. As nothing comes after `(.-)`, it will always match the empty string.

To fix this, simply use the greedy quantifier `*` (zero or more occurrences). `line:match("%s*(.-),%s*(.*)")`. This will match anything after the spacing after the first comma to the end of the string.

Furthermore, if you want to trim trailing spacing, use `line:match("%s*(.-),%s*(.-)%s*$")`. Note that I've changed `.*` back to `.-` since now there is `%s*$` after it which must match: `$` anchors the pattern at the end of the line, meaning `.-` can't stop matching early; `%s*` consumes all trailing spacing before the end of the line.

Reading CSV is easy enough that you probably won't need a library for it.

Comment: Wow thank you for explaining how pattern matching works and not only giving me the answer. This totally worked and I actually get what it is doing now. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not write new code for that purpose. There are a [a lot of code available](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaCsv) with really permissive licenses. I personally use [lua-csv](https://github.com/geoffleyland/lua-csv/) which can be used like this:

```
local Csv  = require("csv.lua")
local File = Csv.open(Filename)
-- Parse all the lines
if File then
  for Line in File:lines() do
    for Index = 1, #Line do
      print("COL", Index, Line[Index])
    end
  end
  -- Close file
  File:close()
else
  print("ERROR:", Filename)
end
```

Comment: It looks like [lua-csv](https://github.com/geoffleyland/lua-csv/) hasn't been updated for 8 years (at the time of writing).

Comment: Thank you for the alternative but I was trying to implement it without using a library for it, I should have mentioned that in my original post.